# if i select january as month and 2018 as year so display only january 2018 full calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

i have two input fields, first is select month and second one is select year. If i select january as month and 2018 as year then display calendar only that selected values. Others are only readable not selected.

Comment: grate statements so.... where's the question?

Comment: question is that i want to display calendar of particular selected month and year. is this possible ?

Comment: depends on the calendar library you use